# Can't access ESXi console after restart, vCenter is powered off

Tags: vmware-esxi, vmware-vcenter

We have a vCenter 6.5 U3 hosted in one ESXi 6.5 U3, the host got restarted and vCenter wasn't set to automatically start, now vCenter is powered off and something is preventing us to log on ESXi.

If I try to log on web console I get 'Connection refused'

Already tried to restart host.

hostd service is not running, it doesn't start even if I do services.sh restart.

vpxa is running but I've checked logs and it has some errors:

'

2021-06-22T15:09:26.915Z error vpxa[A85EB70] [Originator@6876 sub=hostdcnx] Failed to discover version: N3Vim5Fault9HttpFault9ExceptionE(vim.fault.HttpFault)

--> [context]zKq7AUoCAgAAAO4W+gAYdnB4YQAAHywubGlidm1hY29yZS5zbwAA4lUSAG+8DQGhcS92cHhhAAFNci8BeHUvAVd4LwE9ey8BhY8pATGQIgG6DSMBLi4iAclyFgHu2CYBq9kmAfzUJgDPiigByXIWABObIAA+nyAA5eYgAGSqLgLKbABsaWJwdGhyZWFkLnNvLjAAAz5MDWxpYmMuc28uNgA=[/context]

2021-06-22T15:09:26.919Z warning vpxa[A85EB70] [Originator@6876 sub=hostdcnx] Could not resolve version for authenticating to host agent

2021-06-22T15:09:46.922Z verbose vpxa[A81CB70] [Originator@6876 sub=hostdcnx] Creating temporary connect spec: localhost:443

2021-06-22T15:09:46.923Z warning vpxa[A8A0B70] [Originator@6876 sub=Default] Failed to connect socket; <io_obj p:0x05bb6b88, h:15, <TCP '0.0.0.0:0'>, <TCP '127.0.0.1:443'>>, e: system:111(Connection refused)

2021-06-22T15:09:46.923Z error vpxa[A81CB70] [Originator@6876 sub=Default] [FetchOverHttp] Error in sending request - Connection refused

'

vmkwarning.log

'

2021-06-22T14:48:11.672Z cpu36:66042)WARNING: WARN: smartpqi: calc_host_cmd_timeout_in_ms:859: Very low timeout value! 3000ms

2021-06-22T14:48:14.677Z cpu1:65823)WARNING: NFS: 1183: Invalid volume UUID mpx.vmhba32:C0:T0:L0:5

2021-06-22T14:48:14.681Z cpu16:65828)WARNING: NFS: 1183: Invalid volume UUID mpx.vmhba32:C0:T0:L0:8

2021-06-22T14:48:14.731Z cpu9:65821)WARNING: NFS: 1183: Invalid volume UUID mpx.vmhba32:C0:T0:L0:6

2021-06-22T14:48:14.876Z cpu1:65946)WARNING: NMP: nmpUnclaimPath:1603: Physical path "vmhba33:C0:T0:L0" is the last path to NMP device "Unregistered Device". The device has been unregistered.

2021-06-22T14:48:14.876Z cpu1:65946)WARNING: ScsiPath: 7180: Remove path: vmhba33:C0:T0:L0

2021-06-22T14:48:15.171Z cpu1:65826)WARNING: NFS: 1183: Invalid volume UUID mpx.vmhba32:C0:T0:L0:8

2021-06-22T14:48:15.175Z cpu15:65827)WARNING: NFS: 1183: Invalid volume UUID mpx.vmhba32:C0:T0:L0:6

2021-06-22T14:48:15.205Z cpu2:65824)WARNING: NFS: 1183: Invalid volume UUID mpx.vmhba32:C0:T0:L0:5

2021-06-22T14:48:15.355Z cpu0:66993)WARNING: xpt_scsi_adapter_discover:1224: unable to find target 1: No connection

2021-06-22T14:48:16.742Z cpu21:65833)WARNING: NFS: 1183: Invalid volume UUID mpx.vmhba32:C0:T0:L0:6

2021-06-22T14:48:16.746Z cpu2:65831)WARNING: NFS: 1183: Invalid volume UUID mpx.vmhba32:C0:T0:L0:8

2021-06-22T14:48:16.796Z cpu13:65825)WARNING: NFS: 1183: Invalid volume UUID mpx.vmhba32:C0:T0:L0:5

2021-06-22T14:48:16.924Z cpu24:67096)WARNING: xpt_scsi_adapter_discover:1224: unable to find target 1: No connection

2021-06-22T14:48:55.654Z cpu3:69475)WARNING: kbdmode_set:519: invalid keyboard mode 4: Not supported

2021-06-22T14:50:22.349Z cpu31:66140)WARNING: kbdmode_set:519: invalid keyboard mode 4: Not supported

'

vobd.log

'

2021-06-22T15:02:56.004Z: Abandoned event (esx.audit.net.firewall.config.changed) after 6 failures.

2021-06-22T15:02:56.004Z: Abandoned event (esx.audit.dcui.enabled) after 6 failures.

2021-06-22T15:02:56.004Z: Abandoned event (esx.audit.host.boot) after 6 failures.

2021-06-22T15:02:56.004Z: Abandoned event (esx.audit.account.locked) after 6 failures.

2021-06-22T15:02:56.004Z: Abandoned event (esx.audit.shell.enabled) after 6 failures.

2021-06-22T15:02:56.004Z: Abandoned event (esx.audit.ssh.enabled) after 6 failures.

'

If I try to run any command on ESXi shell I get 'Connection refused', I suppose this is because hostd isn't running correctly.

Any help is welcome. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

I guess device mpx.vmhba32:C0:T0:L0:X is your boot device as partitions are unreadable (*Invalid volume UUID*). Boot from ISO and check filesystem and if storage adapter is fine and if host is connected (*unable to find target 1: No connection*)...